# Wordpress post__not_in() function not excluding current post in widget array

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

This is a widget that came with a theme and it's not excluding the listing item from the sidebar. This pulls 3 real estate listings from the same area. *But* it fails to exclude the current item.

Must be some issue with `post__not_in()` but I don't see the issue. Anyone know that function?

```
function listingsInSameAreaWidget() { ?>

<aside id="other-listings-in-same-area" class="widget left">
<h4><?php _e('Other Listings in Same Area', 'theme_textdomain'); ?></h4>
<ul id="newlistings">
<?php
$author = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$city = get_the_term_list(ID, 'city');
$post_id = get_post($post->ID)->ID;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'city' => $city,
    'post__not_in' =>$post->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);

//query_posts($args);
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'city' => $city,
    'post__not_in' =>$post->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => 3, )

);  
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
    <li>
        <?php ct_status_sm(); ?>
        <?php ct_first_image_tn_left(); ?>
        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
        <p class="location"><?php city_and_state(); ?></p>
        <p class="propinfo"><?php beds(); ?> <?php _e('Bed', 'theme_textdomain'); ?>, <?php baths(); ?> <?php _e('Bath', 'theme_textdomain'); ?></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li> 
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
</aside>

<?php
}

register_sidebar_widget('Other Listings in Same Area', 'listingsInSameAreaWidget');
```

Comment: Are there more specifics I can add to help solve this issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OK I found the solution. The id was not passing to the widget:

```
'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID()),
```

Answer (score 13):

It should be an `array`

```
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
```

Comment: Hi Sheikh, replaced that in the 2 spots it shows in the code and it gives the same result.

Comment: Where did the `$post->ID` come from ?

Comment: Well I don't know.. this is in widgets.php that came with the theme. Here's the whole file: http://pastebin.com/jfGCA717